# LED Circuit Safety Next to Paper

Tags: led, safety

I'm making a bookshelf diorama out of a old book, and I want to install an led light circuit that turns on when the cover is opened. This means I'll be running small wires through and next to paper, and I want to be very sure there's no risk of fire. A breadboard of the circuit is below; 6V source out of view, the resistor is 1k ohm.

*Mitigations*: I expect the circuit to be on relatively short periods of time, as I'll be placing the switch to close only when positive force is applied (i.e. a person holding the cover of the book open). I also plan to put heat-shrink tubing on all exposed wire, and use hot glue to hold the leds in place.

Is this a wise thing to do at all? What kind of risks am I running, and what's the best way of mitigating those risks?

[image]

Comment: What's your source of power? Batteries? A wallwart?

Comment: @ErikR 2 3V watch battery cells in a holder (which has a switch on it)

Comment: No worries, then. Here's a short-circuit test of an Energizer CR2032: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C7sXUg5N6M Note: the explosion was caused by charging the CR2032, not by shorting it.

Comment: The device that the camera pans to at 1:20 in the video is a high-voltage generator that Joe made. He uses it for his multimeter testing.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty cool. Seems like the short risk is less than I might have feared

Comment: It would be a good idea to read the datasheet for the battery. The notes for the video have this link for the Energizer battery: https://data.energizer.com/PDFs/lithiumion_psds.pdf On page 3 there is a section titled "Handling" which talks about shorts, and it says that a short "could generate enough heat to burn skin". Note that these datasheets are conservative for legal reasons. If you use a little electrical tape to minimize the possibility of a short you should be fine. A shorted battery quickly loses energy and won't last long.

Answer (score 1):

I’d be impressed if you could get enough energy out of a couple of watch battery cells to start any sort of fire.  In your application you have a 1k resistor and so even if that’s placed directly across the battery it will dissipate 36mW which is not a concern.  If the resistor were to short and the LED took excessive current it might fail, but wouldn’t generate much temperature rise because the plastic encapsulation is relatively large.  A direct short across the battery would be the worst case.  I can’t quote figures but I’ve never known a watch battery become even significantly warm when under heavy load; they just don’t have enough energy in them.  Bigger batteries are a different matter.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm an electronics noob and have a (un?)healthy fear of all things electric